# Why does a javascript RegExp created by /.../ work but the same created via "new RegExp" does not?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm confused as to what the difference here is and why one works and the other does not. Can someone explain this?

```
//The string to search through
var str = "This is a string /* with some //stuff in here";

//This one will NOT work, it alerts an empty "match"
var regEx = new RegExp( "(\/\*)", "g" );

//This one also will NOT work (tried just in case escaping was the issue)
var regEx2 = new RegExp( "(/*)", "g" );

//This one DOES work
var regEx3 = /(\/\*)/g;

var match = null;

//Trying the first one, it alerts ","
if ( match = regEx.exec( str ) ) alert( match );

//Trying the second one, it alerts ","
if ( match = regEx2.exec( str ) ) alert( match );

//Trying the third one, it alerts "/*,/*" - it works!
if ( match = regEx3.exec( str ) ) alert( match );
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`\` is the escape characters in *strings*. Hence, to create a **literal** backslash as escape character for the *regular expressions*, you need to escape it itself:

```
var regEx = new RegExp("(/\\*)", "g" );
```

If you use Chrome or Safari (maybe also in Firebug), you can easily see the resulting expression by executing the code in the console:

> > `new RegExp( "(/\*)", "g" );`
>   `/(/*)/g`
>
> > `new RegExp( "(/\\*)", "g" );`
>   `/(/\*)/g`

P.S.: No need to escape the slash in the string (though it might be ignored in the regex).

Comment: yes! Thanks that's the problem! Duh, I was forgetting to escape the escape characters. :)

Comment: As an aside, to complete your answer, you should notice that the two syntaxes produce exactly the same object, even if it is not the main subject of the question.

Answer (score 1):

In order to get the equivalent of `/(\/\*)/g`, you want `new RegExp("(\\/\\*)", "g")`.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are escaping your forward slashes in your RegExp object when they don't need to be escaped there. You also need to escape you backslashes.

The equivalent of: `/(\/\*)/g`

Is: `var regEx = new RegExp( "(/\\*)", "g" );`

Comment: Escaping the forward-slashes in the string version doesn't do any harm, it just isn't necessary.