# JavaScript RegExp.test() not returning true

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to validate that a password matches my specified pattern.  I got the password pattern from http://html5pattern.com/.  It should validate that my password contains uppercase, lowercase, and a number.  I have checked the string 'Asdf1' on the above site and it works fine.  I also added my regex pattern to W3Schools "Try It Yourself" example and it also returned TRUE.  However when I try to check the string pattern in my code it returns FALSE, as it does in JSFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/rnwilis/9okh6ppc/5/

Here is my named function:

```
function validatePassword(data){
    var testStr = "Asdf1";
    var pattern = new RegExp('^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?!.*\s).*$', 'g');      
    var result = pattern.test(testStr);      
    return result;    
}
```

As you can see, I created a self executing anonymous function in Fiddle.  This is a named function that I will call in my code.  I hard-coded the string just to try to get the expected results. Ultimately testStr = data as I am passing in the user input password to the named function.  I have also tried creating the RegExp object with and without the 'g' tag, which I don't really think makes a difference in this circumstance.

Comment: Since you are using a string literal for creating the regular expression, all ``\`` have to be escaped. Or use a regular expression literal instead. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/6837580/218196

Comment: Do you mean like /^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?!.*\s).*$/

Comment: @John yep, and don't use `g` modifier.

Comment: Worked great.  Thanks for the help.  Sry about duplicate, I did search first :(